# How to pass the current item in the Observable Collection which is being parsed to the Converter

Tags: xaml, mvvm, binding, uwp, observablecollection

I have an observable collection of an `Activity` class which on run-time can be of different types like `IssueEvent`, `AbcEvent` etc and I need to detect the type for every element so that I can modify them accordingly.

The Observable Collection is named `FeedList` which binds to a ListView in my UI.

Currently I can just pass the whole *ObservableCollection* to the converter everytime an element is rendered and have an integer increment so that I can track which element to retrieve from the collection.

But isn't this very memory heavy code as the *ObservableCollection* is passed again and again for every element? Is there a better way to do what I am trying to do here?

Thanks.

Here's the code for my ListView

```
 <ListView x:Name="ListView" ItemsSource="{Binding FeedList}">

                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>                                                         
                           <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ListView, Path=DataContext.FeedList}"/>                              

                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Comment: It's unclear why you bind the TextBlock Text to the FeedList property of the ListView's DataContext. Shouldn't there be just a binding to the current element, optionally with an appropriate binding converter?

Comment: @Clemens I have to change the text in the `TextBox` based on the type of current `ListItem` that's why I need the current element in the converter which can be retrieved through `FeedList`.

Comment: The current element is already in the DataContext of the ListViewItem and hence also in that of the elements of the ItemTemplate. You can access it by a simple binding like `Text="{Binding}"`. If you need to access an item property, you would write `Text="{Binding MyProperty}"`. You could as well use a converter there, like `Text="{Binding Converter={StaticResource MyConverter}}"`.

Comment: @Clemens So stupid of me that I forgot the {Binding .} syntax and just made a very simple problem much complex. Anyways, thanks very much for your time :)